# Set a value for an element found with select() but return the whole json

Tags: json, jq, edit

I have a JSON like this:

```
{
  "name": "com.company1.package1",
  "version": "0.2",
  "dependencies": {
    "com.company1.package2": "0.1",
    "com.company2.package1": "2.3"
  }
}
```

And I want to change all dependencies with keys starting with "com.company1" to "0.2".

I managed to change it with this:

```
jq '.dependencies | with_entries(select(.key|startswith("com.company1"))) | .[]="0.2"'
```

But this only returns

```
{
  "com.company1.package2": "0.2"
}
```

I would like to get the whole initial JSON with only this value changed. Like so:

```
{
  "name": "com.company1.package1",
  "version": "0.2",
  "dependencies": {
    "com.company1.package2": "0.2",
    "com.company2.package1": "2.3"
  }
}
```

How could go about that?

Comment: Please add your desired output (no description, no images, no links) for that sample input to your question (no comment).

Answer (score 2):

You were almost there. Use the update operator `|=` and inside the update a direct assignment `.value = "0.2"`.

```sh
jq '.dependencies |= with_entries(select(.key | startswith("com.company1")).value = "0.2")'
```

```json
{
  "name": "com.company1.package1",
  "version": "0.2",
  "dependencies": {
    "com.company1.package2": "0.2",
    "com.company2.package1": "2.3"
  }
}
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/vzNjTyKfa-)

Comment: What if there is another line like `"com.company1.package2": "42",` in `dependencies`?

Comment: @Cyrus If `.dependencies` contained multiple entries with the same field name (which is valid but pointless JSON) a JSON parser would immediately eliminate the duplicates. [Check it out](https://jqplay.org/s/bQXQCUjiVX) by just running `.` on your suggested input. If your extra entry had a unique key as does for example `"com.company1.package3": "42"`, all entries (starting with the given string) including the new one [will be updated](https://jqplay.org/s/c-khfvBxFx).

Comment: Thank you for your explanation.

Answer (score 1):

You're projecting to a filtered view of your object (with all the `|` in your filter). Since you just want to do assignments, make sure that is at the top of your filter. `select` the properties you want to adjust then do the assignment.

It'll be easier if you used paths to do this, since you're filtering based on the path.

```
setpath(path(.dependencies[]) | select(.[1] | startswith("com.company1")); "0.2")
```

which produces:

```json
{
  "name": "com.company1.package1",
  "version": "0.2",
  "dependencies": {
    "com.company1.package2": "0.2",
    "com.company2.package1": "2.3"
  }
}
```

[jqplay](https://jqplay.org/s/JfzXELoOxj)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a ruby JSON to do this:

```
ruby -r JSON -e 'd=JSON.parse($<.read)
d["dependencies"].each {|k,v| d["dependencies"][k]="0.2" if k[/\bcompany1\b/] }
puts d.to_json' file | jq .

# using jq to pretty print...
```

Or, later versions of ruby, you can do:

```
ruby -r JSON -e 'd=JSON.parse($<.read)
d["dependencies"].each {|k,v| d["dependencies"][k]="0.2" if k[/\bcompany1\b/] }
puts JSON.pretty_generate(d)' file
```

Either prints:

```
{
  "name": "com.company1.package1",
  "version": "0.2",
  "dependencies": {
    "com.company1.package2": "0.2",
    "com.company2.package1": "2.3"
  }
}
```